# Time travel to WWII to try to change the course of the war

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I'm looking for a book that is at least 20 years old.

A group of people travel back in time to WWII. They try to change the course of the war and ultimately succeed, however in the end it is revealed that they were actually in an alternate reality, and not changing history at all.

Answer (score 11):

I'm pretty sure the novel you're looking for is [*The Proteus Operation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Proteus_Operation) by James P. Hogan. I haven't read it in a quite some time but, from what I remember, it fits your description perfectly.